# PHP Anonymous Function, Use Keyword & Variable Scope Issue

Tags: php, scope, anonymous-function, slim

For reference I'm using the SLIM framework

My issue is where you see the commented out **print_r commands in the code below**.  For some reason the variable is **showing the correct values right before the !in_array function**.  I'm not sure what is going on, but when you pass the variable `$allowedUserTypes` into that function it seems to be using (I'm guessing an older version of the variable from somewhere) incorrect values.  Not sure how this is possible though since it works right before that function??.  I'm guessing there is some kind of scoping issue or I'm misunderstanding the use of the 'USE' keyword in an anonymous function.

```
$validate_user = function ($allowedUserTypes, $templateFolder = 'api'){
    return function() use ($allowedUserTypes, $templateFolder){
        global $app, $settings, $user, $device;

        set_template_directory($templateFolder);

        $errors = array();

        $validated = true;//assumed valid until proven false.

        //check session variables only if not token api call
        if($app->request()->params('token') == ''){

            //Check for expiration date hack
            if($_SESSION['remember']==false){
                $now = new DateTime();
                $now->modify("-30 minutes");
            }else{
                $now = new DateTime();
                $now->modify("-14 days");
            }

            //If the cookie still exists then it might have a time value in it.  See if it's set.
            if(isset($_SESSION['time'])){
                //If time now (minus minute) is greater than the session time then hack attempted.
                if($now > $_SESSION['time']){ 
                    $errors["errors"]["generic"][] = "Permission denied.  Cookie expired.";
                    $validated = false;
                    unset($_SESSION['time']);
                    unset($_SESSION['remember']);
                    unset($_SESSION['userid']);
                    unset($user);
                }
            }
        }

        if(isset($user)){
            $usertype = Usertype::find_by_id($user->usertype_id);//get all usertypes

            //print_r($allowedUserTypes); --> shows Admin, Manager, Franchise Admin, Franchise Manager
            if(!in_array($usertype->name,$allowedUserTypes)){
                //print_r($allowedUserTypes); --> shows only Admin, Manager ??

                $errors["errors"]["generic"][] = "Permission denied for user type :".$usertype->name;
                $validated = false;
            }
        }else{
            $errors["errors"]["generic"][] = "Permission denied.  User not logged in.  Please log in and try again.";
            $validated = false;
        }

        if($validated==false){
            $errors["command"] = "Error";
            $errors['message'] = "User could not be validated.";

            if($templateFolder=='templates'){
                $app->render('shared/header.php',       array('settings' => $settings));
                $app->render($device.'/header.php',     array('settings' => $settings, 'pagetitle'  => 'Pool Service USA | Error Page', 'user' => $user));
                $app->render($device.'/error.php',      array('settings' => $settings, 'errors' => $errors,'device' => $device));
                $app->render($device.'/footer.php',     array('settings' => $settings));
                $app->render('shared/footer.php',       array('settings' => $settings));
            }else{ //API Based Errors
                $app->render('shared/error.php', array(
                    'settings'  => $settings,
                    'errors'    => $errors,
                    'device'    => $device
                ));
            }

            $app->stop();//stop rendering to this point.
        }
    };
};
```

I'll show the 2 lines I use to call to this function right before I call it and after incase that has anything to do with it.

```
$app->map('/api/remove-user'                        ,'get_user',$validate_user(array('Admin','Manager','Franchise Admin','Franchise Manager')),$remove_record_for_class('User'))                                ->via('GET', 'POST');
$app->map('/api/view-user'                          ,'get_user',$validate_user(array('Admin','Manager','Franchise Admin','Franchise Manager')),$view_results_for_class('User'))                                 ->via('GET', 'POST');
```

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Is there any reason to use anonymous function as the only code in another function. I understand it should work the same if you remove `return function() use ($allowedUserTypes, $templateFolder){` and it's correcponding ending `}`.

Comment: I had to do that because slim requires a function returned to it in its $app-map() function, but I found the solution, I made a mistake by calling $app->map twice, I think what happened is git merged in a copy of it and screwed me up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was running the $app->map('') command twice by accident, in one case sending only 'Admin' and 'Manager' which caused the error.  So was a stupid error on my part :(.  Just goes to show to watch out for this stuff.